# Getting single variable from multiple NetCDF files using loop in R

Tags: r, netcdf, netcdf4

If I have n files named nc.data_1, nc.data_2... nc.data_n, how can I get the same variable from all of the files and store them into a single array in R? (i.e. (a) getting the time then (b) getting precipitation data with dimensions: [lon, lat, time] = [144, 91, 24] from n files respectively). The code below is what I've done so far.

Data path: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/m8u3xwm5za7m7mc/AACHq2AjeZaxHm1sEhaOJ_g2a/2011?dl=0

```
## Call library functions for future plot
library(abind)
library(fields)
library(maps)
library(ncdf4)

## create an empty list that saves the incoming files
nc.data<-list()
list.filenames<-list.files(pattern = ".nc")

## Read in all data files using a loop
for(i in 1:length(list.filenames)){
nc.data[[i]]<-nc_open(list.filenames[[i]])
}

## Getting lat and lon from a single file since they're the same for all files
lat_2x25 <- ncvar_get(nc.data[[1]], 'lat')
lon_2x25 <- ncvar_get(nc.data[[1]], 'lon')
```

For the time variable, I can't use the same method as the lat and lon since the time in each file are different(each file store the data of one day)

Comment: Why not just use `raster::stack(x)` or `raster::brick(x)`, where x is a list of the filenames you want to stack.  I would then probably keep them as bricks or stacks (much better for spatial data than an array), but if you *really* need an array instead then `as.array` is your friend.

Comment: Did you try the solution below?  Was it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Not an R solution, but if in linux you could just use CDO first (I'm assuming you wrote the filename back to front as the extension ".nc" usually goes at the end):

```
cdo merge data_*.nc merge_file.nc
cdo selvar,variable_name merge_file.nc variable.nc
```

then you can simply open and read the latter in R.